# Vue, await for Watch

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuex

i have similar architecture in my app.

```
computed(){ 
   someStoreValue = this.$store.someStoreValue; 
}
watch() { 
   someStoreValue() = async function () { 
    //do some async action 
   
   }
}, 
methods: { 
  someAction() {        
     this.$store.someStoreValue = 'NEW VALUE'     
     //await for "watch" 

     //do stuff

  }
}
```

I need to "someAction" await for "someStoreValue" watcher ends.
I need this kind of architecture someStoreValue can be changed in many places.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, you can't make your watchers async, which is pretty senseless since the data you are after has already arrived.

```
someStoreValue(newValue, oldValue) { 
    // But you can still call other async functions. 
    // Async functions are just functions that returns a promise. Thus:
    doSomeAsyncAction().then(this.someAction)
}
```

Still, why not just do your async stuff in someAction instead?

```
watch:{ 
    someStoreValue(newValue, oldValue) { 
        this.someAction()
    }
},
methods:{
    async someAction(){
        await doSomeAsyncStuff() // What prevents you from doing this?
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that once you make the `someAction` method asynchronous, you have to `await` this.someAction` method call and you will be forced to use the async keyword on the watch. I don't imagine there would be any problems doing that.

Comment: The first example uses a .then chain, no need for await. The second puts all the waiting in methods and no need to make watch async, which is impossible anyway.

Comment: True. I just saw that. However, the use of `.then` and `async-await `doesn't help with consistency, won't you say? It works, but it just rubs me some kinda way.

Comment: Yes, I would also prefer to stick to one syntax.

Comment: `this.someAction()` is an async method and you are forced to write async keyword on `this.someAction()` inside watch which again throws errors and I find the solution not useful.

Comment: why can't make the watchers async? I thought you can do `watch:{ async  someStoreValue(newValue, oldValue) { ` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag and wait for it.

```js
data() {
   return {
      flag: false
   }
},
watch() { 
   someStoreValue() = async function () { 
    //do some async action 
  
     flag = true;  
   }
}, 
methods: { 
  async someAction() {        
     this.$store.someStoreValue = 'NEW VALUE'     
     await new Promise((resolve) => {
       if (this.flag) {
         resolve();
       } else {
         const unwatch = this.$watch('flag', (newVal) => {
           if (newVal) {
             unwatch();
             resolve();
           }
         });
       }
      });

     //do stuff

  }
}
```

Maybe in this case the [@ippi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188673/6904888) solution is better, but you can use this approach in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is related, but maybe not exactly answering the question.

I wanted to perform an action once per created but I wanted to wait on a value being loaded by Vuex (triggered by another component). Here's what I came up with.

```
// outside of component
//   this is to avoid race condition of the eager watcher
let resolve: Function;
const promise = new Promise((res: Function) => {
  resolve = res;
});


// inside component
created() {
  promise.then(this.someAction);
},
watch: {
  someValueToWatch: {
    handler(val) {
      if (val) resolve();
    },
    immediate: true,
  },
},
methods: {
  someAction() {
     // do something once per created/mounted only after someValueToWatch is loaded
  },
},
```